# Can I add to each url necessary to me prefix?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a route

```
      routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{langCode}/{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Services", action = "Index", langCode = "en" }
        );
```

Is there a way to link to each added langCode?
I do not want to add every link something like this

```
   routeValues: new { langCode = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["langCode"] }
```

ps:

```
   @Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: new { langCode = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["langCode"] })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to write every time:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: new { langCode = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["langCode"] })
```

if the langCode route value is present in current url then it will be automatically reused by the framework itself. For example if the current url looks like `/en/Account/Register` and  you call  `@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account")` then the resulting url will be `/en/Account/Login`